# My PHP code is working correcly but when I open it via link on instagram or facebook, there is written, that column 'name' cannot be null

Tags: php, pdo, null

The code works correcly on web and also via mobile. The problem begins If it's opened as a link via instagram or facebook social page.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
$title = "xxxxxx";
require("header.php");



$conn = new PDO('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM sutaz_tabulka WHERE meno = :meno');
$meno = $_POST['meno'];
$sql->execute(array(':meno' => $meno));
$result = $sql->fetchObject();

if ($result->total > 0) 
{
    echo '<div class="dakujem" style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 200px; padding: 50px 5px; color: white; background-color: rgb(220, 20, 60);">Nedávno ste sa už zapojili do našej súťaže!</div>';     
}
else
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sutaz_tabulka (meno) VALUES(:meno)");
    $stmt->bindValue(':meno', $meno);
    $stmt->execute(array(':meno' => $meno));
}
?>
```

I am attaching the error message below:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'meno' cannot be null' in /data/5/8/582bf4f8-549d-48a3-833c-52986c8a8ca5/zapojsavyhraj.sk/web/post-comment.php:30 Stack trace: #0 /data/5/8/582bf4f8-549d-48a3-833c-52986c8a8ca5/zapojsavyhraj.sk/web/post-comment.php(30): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /data/5/8/582bf4f8-549d-48a3-833c-52986c8a8ca5/zapojsavyhraj.sk/web/post-comment.php on line 30

Answer (score 0):

When you open this page as a link
`$_POST['meno'];` is necessarily null, it can contain data if you call this script via AJAX

So if you want to open this page as a link you have to add a condition `if isset($_POST['meno']) or if !empty($_POST['meno']):`

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
    $title = "Zapoj sa a vyhraj";
    require("header.php");

    //this condition verifies that POST memo exists
    if (isset($_POST['meno']))
    {
    $conn = new PDO('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM sutaz_tabulka WHERE meno = :meno');
    $meno = $_POST['meno'];
    $sql->execute(array(':meno' => $meno));
    $result = $sql->fetchObject();

    if ($result->total > 0) 
    {
        echo '<div class="dakujem" style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 200px; padding: 50px 5px; color: white; background-color: rgb(220, 20, 60);">Nedávno ste sa už zapojili do našej súťaže!</div>';     
    }
    else
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sutaz_tabulka (meno) VALUES(:meno)");
        $stmt->bindValue(':meno', $meno);
        $stmt->execute(array(':meno' => $meno));
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I made it as you wrote, but also did not work. It Doesnt work because, when I submit a form from mobile opened as a link, there is NULL value of "name". On the other hand, through web it works correctly.

Comment: @DianaViťazková it is the same error message ?

Comment: Yes this is normal, because the if blocks the SQL query and the success message if POST['meno'] is null to avoid the error.
This is not the case when you send the form correctly because POST['meno'] will have the value you entered in the input of the form but not if you go directly to the page because POST['meno'] is null since it has no data. In this case you can either output the success echo outside the if isset so that the message is displayed no matter what or add an echo saying please complete the form

Comment: But why I have to put an echo saying "complete the form" when my input doesnt let you submit form without filling it. So I have to put there something, inspite of this fact it doesnt show anything on the output. (but Im  still talking about opening the site via mobile via link on this page, not directly. Because directly the site is working). I dont know if you understand me.